# Regex for validate words also with accents

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics

My regex validates words (also containing numbers), but words that have accents are not validating correctly.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/i.test(word)
```

For example:

```
car => true

plantas => true

avião => false (but this should be also true)
```

What should I change in my regex to also work with accents?

Comment: Just add the characters that you want to be validated: ex `[\wáéíóúâêîôû]*$/i`

Comment: _"Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."_ Is this Javascript?

Comment: @ElChiniNet How do I add this to the current regex?

Comment: @IbnClaudius: That is supposed to *replace* yours - like `/^[\wáéíóúâêîôûã]*$/i`. Just add the chars you need to the character class.

Comment: This is javascript?

Comment: I had the same issue with Greek and I defined character range with help from [https://unicode-table.com/en/](https://unicode-table.com/en/). For example: `[a-zA-ZΆΈ-ώἀ-ῼ]*`

Comment: Yes, its javascript!